# ng-click fires multiple times inside ng-repeat ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a weird quirk that appears to only be happening in ie9 with AngularJS.

I have a repeated button with ng-repeat and a function with ng-click. When the button is clicked the function appears to run multiple times and goes between the buttons. I've tried to remove as much conflicting code as possible and whittled it down to these parts.

I have come to the conclusion that it only happens on the add remove class if else statement, when this is removed it appears to work ok.

Here is my code:

```
            <div class="row multiple-question">
                    <button 
                     data-num="{{item.QuestionNo}}" 
                     class="ansbtn" data-ans="{{ answer.AnswerValue }}" 
                     ng-click="triggerNext(item.QuestionNo, answer.AnswerValue)" 
                     ng-repeat="answer in item.Answers">
                    <span class="letter num{{ $index + 1 }}"></span>
                        <h3>
                            <span class="circle right">
                                <span class="icon-checkmark"></span>
                            </span>
                        </h3>
                        <p>{{ answer.Answer }}</p>
                       <span class="arrow-right-button"></span>
                    </button>       
            </div>
```

And the function code is here:

```
$scope.triggerNext = function(QuestionNo, AnswerValue) {
    console.log('function run');
    console.log(QuestionNo);
    console.log(AnswerValue);

    if($('.ansbtn[data-ans="'+AnswerValue+'"]').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ansbtn[data-ans="'+AnswerValue+'"]').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.ansbtn[data-num="'+QuestionNo+'"]').removeClass('active');
        $('.ansbtn[data-ans="'+AnswerValue+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to enclose the button with a div or span element, and having that serve the ng-repeat, keeping your ng-click on each button.

Comment: Hey, yeah I actually had the buttons encased in a container originally, what would happen is that if you clicked the 2nd button of any question, it would repeatedly click between buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just posting my solution, although the issue still remained if I stuck to using ng-click, the issue went away if I binded the button click to the document, this is NOT the right way to do it as I understand. But it worked.